# Apache Wicket Gmap3 does not display the map in the div

Tags: java, google-maps, maven, dependencies, wicket

I am using NetBeans to run a Wicket application with just one div in which a google maps should be .
I added the dependency from NetBeans ,wicketstuff-gmap3. I've tried both available versions in Netbeans : 1.4.0 and 1.5.0 and in both , DEPLOYMENT and DEVELOPMENT mode , the map simply not appears.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>wicketstuff-gmap3</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>
```

Java code :

```
import org.wicketstuff.gmap.GMap;
import org.wicketstuff.gmap.api.GLatLng;

    public class HomePage extends WebPage {

        public HomePage() {
            GMap map = new GMap("map");
            map.setStreetViewControlEnabled(false);
            map.setScaleControlEnabled(true);
            map.setScrollWheelZoomEnabled(true);
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(52.47649, 13.228573));
            add(map);
        }
    }
```

HTML :

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div wicket:id="map"></div>     
    </body>
</html>
```

The web app runs and simply display a blank pange . Anyone know how to solve this ? Thank you !

Comment: What sets the size of the "map: div?

Comment: nothing , should i have a size for the div ?

Comment: If you don't set the size, it won't have one and you won't be able to see it.  Don't know if that is your problem.

Comment: no , this is not the problem ,thanks anyway

Comment: Another issue (but not necessarily the problem),  GLatLng is a part of the [deprecated and turned off Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)

Answer (score 2):

As I was running in the same issue now. I will just leave the solution for me here:

First, it is necessary to make sure that the div containing possibly empty map will be actually visible. To do this style the element in which you create the map.

```
<div wicket:id="map" class="map"></div>
```

In associated css then do something in a way:

```
.map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

The second thing which will probably prevent you from seeing the map is the fact that as of a current time it is necessary to specify API key in order to use the GMaps API. This means following update to the creation of the map in the code.

```
GMap map = new GMap("map", new GMapHeaderContributor("http", "hereGoesTheApiKey"));
```

If you don't have key there is a guideline from Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the html:

```
<div wicket:id="map" style="height: 400px"></div>
```